# OpenMP slower than serial codes

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to do the parallelization of a serial preconditioned conjugate gradient solver codes for 3D fire simulation using OpenMP (Intel compiler). But the performance seems not to be improved.

The grid dimension is 79x81x79 and the solver can converge after 565 iterations. The serial codes cost 3.39 seconds and the OpenMP version needs 3.86 seconds on Intel i7 2600 **(OS: openSUSE 13.1)**.

Please help me to check  the codes. Thanks a lot.

```
//   preconditioned conjugate gradient solver  ...
void PCGSSolver::solveNew(const Array3D<double>& sn, const Array3D<double>& ae,  const Array3D<double>&aw,
                          const Array3D<double>& as,  const Array3D<double>& an,  const Array3D<double>&at,  const Array3D<double>&ab,
                          const Array3D<double>& ap, Array3D<double>& ptmp){
    std::size_t dimX=sn.getDimI();
    std::size_t dimY=sn.getDimJ();
    std::size_t dimZ=sn.getDimK();


    Array3D<double> p1(dimX,dimY,dimZ,0.0);
    Array3D<double> res(dimX,dimY,dimZ,0.0);
    Array3D<double> d(dimX,dimY,dimZ,0.0);
    Array3D<double> ain(dimX,dimY,dimZ,0.0);


    double tiny=1.0e-30;
#pragma omp parallel
{
        //Jacobi preconditioner
#pragma omp for nowait
    for(std::size_t k=1;k<dimZ-1; k++){
        for(std::size_t j=1; j<dimY-1; j++){
            for(std::size_t i=1; i<dimX-1; i++){
                d(i,j,k)=1./ap(i,j,k);
            }
        }
    }
#pragma omp for nowait
    for(std::size_t k=1;k<dimZ-1; k++){
        for(std::size_t j=1; j<dimY-1; j++){
            for(std::size_t i=1; i<dimX-1; i++){
                res(i,j,k)=ae(i,j,k)*ptmp(i+1,j,k) + aw(i,j,k)*ptmp(i-1,j,k)+an(i,j,k)*ptmp(i,j+1,k)+as(i,j,k)*ptmp(i,j-1,k)+
                                at(i,j,k)*ptmp(i,j,k+1)+ab(i,j,k)*ptmp(i,j,k-1)+sn(i,j,k)-ap(i,j,k)*ptmp(i,j,k);
            }
        }
    }

}


    double big =1.0e+30;
    double s1old=big;
    //start iteration
    for(std::size_t intswp=0; intswp<this->nswpvr; intswp++){

        double alpha=0.0;
        double bbeta=0.0;
        double s1=0.0;
        double s2=0.0;
        double testir=0.0;
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp for reduction(+:s1)
        for(std::size_t k=1;k<dimZ-1; k++){
            for(std::size_t j=1; j<dimY-1; j++){
                for(std::size_t i=1; i<dimX-1; i++){
                    ain(i,j,k)=res(i,j,k)*d(i,j,k);
                    s1+=(res(i,j,k)*ain(i,j,k));
                }
            }
        }

#pragma omp single
{
        bbeta=s1/(s1old+tiny);
}
#pragma omp for
        for(std::size_t k=1;k<dimZ-1; k++){
            for(std::size_t j=1; j<dimY-1; j++){
                for(std::size_t i=1; i<dimX-1; i++){
                    p1(i,j,k)=ain(i,j,k)+bbeta*p1(i,j,k);
                }
            }
        }

#pragma omp for reduction(+:s2)
        for(std::size_t k=1;k<dimZ-1; k++){
            for(std::size_t j=1; j<dimY-1; j++){
                for(std::size_t i=1; i<dimX-1; i++){
                    ain(i,j,k)=ap(i,j,k)*p1(i,j,k)-ae(i,j,k)*p1(i+1,j,k)-aw(i,j,k)*p1(i-1,j,k)-
                                    an(i,j,k)*p1(i,j+1,k)-as(i,j,k)*p1(i,j-1,k)-
                                    at(i,j,k)*p1(i,j,k+1)-ab(i,j,k)*p1(i,j,k-1);
                    s2+=(p1(i,j,k)*ain(i,j,k));
                }
            }
        }

#pragma omp single
{
        alpha=s1/(s2+tiny);
}
#pragma omp for reduction(+:testir)
        for(std::size_t k=1;k<dimZ-1; k++){
            for(std::size_t j=1; j<dimY-1; j++){
                for(std::size_t i=1; i<dimX-1; i++){
                    ptmp(i,j,k)=ptmp(i,j,k)+alpha*p1(i,j,k);
                    res(i,j,k)=res(i,j,k)-alpha*ain(i,j,k);
                    testir+=fabs(res(i,j,k));
                }
            }
        }

}//==openmp region end
        s1old=s1;
        //test stop criteria
        if(testir < ccvar){
            std::cout<<"PCGS solver coverage at "<<(intswp+1)<<" iterations!"<<std::scientific<<testir<<std::endl;
            return;
        }

    }
    std::cout<<"PCGS solver can not coverage "<<std::endl;
}
```

The Array3D is a my 3 dimension array class.

```
#ifndef ARRAY3D_H
#define ARRAY3D_H

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T> class Array3D
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    Array3D(){
        dim_i=dim_j=dim_k=0;
        dim_ij=0;
    }

    Array3D(std::size_t size_i, std::size_t size_j, std::size_t size_k){
        this->resize(size_i,size_j,size_k);
    }

    Array3D(std::size_t size_i, std::size_t size_j, std::size_t size_k,const value_type& defaultValue){
        this->resize(size_i,size_j,size_k,defaultValue);
    }

    virtual ~Array3D(){}

    std::size_t getDimI()const{
        return this->dim_i;
    }

    std::size_t getDimJ()const{
        return this->dim_j;
    }

    std::size_t getDimK()const{
        return this->dim_k;
    }

    //check if valid indices
    bool checkIndices(std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t k){
        return (i<this->dim_i ) && (j<this->dim_j) && (k<this->dim_k);
    }
    void resize(std::size_t size_i, std::size_t size_j, std::size_t size_k,const value_type& defaultValue){
        this->resize(size_i,size_j,size_k);
        this->fillValue(defaultValue);
    }
    //resize the array. The data will be ereased.
    void resize(std::size_t size_i, std::size_t size_j, std::size_t size_k){
        this->dim_i=size_i;
        this->dim_j=size_j;
        this->dim_k=size_k;
        this->dim_ij=this->dim_i*this->dim_j;

        std::size_t totalSize=this->dim_i*this->dim_j*this->dim_k;
        this->data.resize(totalSize);
    }
    std::size_t size()const{
        return this->data.size();
    }

    void fillValue(const value_type& defaultValue){
        std::fill(this->data.begin(),this->data.end(),defaultValue);
    }
    value_type minValue()const{
        return *(std::min_element(data.begin(),data.end()));
    }
    value_type maxValue()const{
        return *(std::max_element(data.begin(),data.end()));
    }

    //Fill the array value using the sum of two array
    void setValueSum(const Array3D& array1, const Array3D& array2){
        size_t minSize=std::min(std::min(array1.data.size(),array2.data.size()),this->data.size());
        for(size_t i=0; i<minSize; i++)
            this->data[i]=array1.data[i]+array2.data[i];
    }

    void clear(){
        dim_i=dim_j=dim_k=0;
        dim_ij=0;
        this->data.clear();
    }

    //get value reference at (i,j,k) or (x,y,z) or (u,v,w)...
    const value_type& operator () (std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t k )const{
        return this->data.at(this->calIndex(i,j,k));
    }

    value_type& operator ()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t k ){
        return this->data.at(this->calIndex(i,j,k));
    }
    //access the raw data by 1D index
    const value_type& operator [] (std::size_t i )const{
        return this->data.at(i);
    }
    value_type& operator [](std::size_t i ){
        return this->data.at(i);
    }
    std::vector<value_type>* rawData(){
        return &(data);
    }
private:
    inline std::size_t calIndex(std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t k )const{
        return k*this->dim_ij+j*this->dim_i+i;
    }

private:
    //dimension of array (i,j,k)(x,y,z)(u,v,w)...
    std::size_t dim_i, dim_j, dim_k;
    //raw data, order is I-J-K
    std::vector<value_type> data;

    //dim_i*dim_j
    std::size_t dim_ij;
};

#endif // ARRAY3D_H
```

I measure the time using a Timer class codes downloaded from internet.

```
    timer.start();
    PCGSSolver solver;
    solver.setTolerance(this->ccvar);
    solver.setIteNum(this->nswpp);
    solver.solveNew(sn,ae,aw,as,an,at,ab,ap,ptmp);
    timer.stop();
    std::cout<<"PCGS time:"<<timer.getElapsedTimeInSec()<<"sec"<<std::endl;
```

Timer.h

```
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Timer.h
// =======
// High Resolution Timer.
// This timer is able to measure the elapsed time with 1 micro-second accuracy
// in both Windows, Linux and Unix system 
//
//  AUTHOR: Song Ho Ahn (song.ahn@gmail.com)
// CREATED: 2003-01-13
// UPDATED: 2006-01-13
//
// Copyright (c) 2003 Song Ho Ahn
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef TIMER_H_DEF
#define TIMER_H_DEF

#ifdef WIN32   // Windows system specific
#include <windows.h>
#else          // Unix based system specific
#include <sys/time.h>
#endif

class Timer
{
public:
    Timer();                                    // default constructor
    ~Timer();                                   // default destructor

    void   start();                             // start timer
    void   stop();                              // stop the timer
    double getElapsedTime();                    // get elapsed time in second
    double getElapsedTimeInSec();               // get elapsed time in second (same as getElapsedTime)
    double getElapsedTimeInMilliSec();          // get elapsed time in milli-second
    double getElapsedTimeInMicroSec();          // get elapsed time in micro-second


protected:


private:
    double startTimeInMicroSec;                 // starting time in micro-second
    double endTimeInMicroSec;                   // ending time in micro-second
    int    stopped;                             // stop flag 
#ifdef WIN32
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;                    // ticks per second
    LARGE_INTEGER startCount;                   //
    LARGE_INTEGER endCount;                     //
#else
    timeval startCount;                         //
    timeval endCount;                           //
#endif
};

#endif // TIMER_H_DEF
```

Timer.cpp

```
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Timer.cpp
// =========
// High Resolution Timer.
// This timer is able to measure the elapsed time with 1 micro-second accuracy
// in both Windows, Linux and Unix system 
//
//  AUTHOR: Song Ho Ahn (song.ahn@gmail.com)
// CREATED: 2003-01-13
// UPDATED: 2006-01-13
//
// Copyright (c) 2003 Song Ho Ahn
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include  "Timer.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// constructor
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Timer::Timer()
{
#ifdef WIN32
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    startCount.QuadPart = 0;
    endCount.QuadPart = 0;
#else
    startCount.tv_sec = startCount.tv_usec = 0;
    endCount.tv_sec = endCount.tv_usec = 0;
#endif

    stopped = 0;
    startTimeInMicroSec = 0;
    endTimeInMicroSec = 0;
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// distructor
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Timer::~Timer()
{
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// start timer.
// startCount will be set at this point.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Timer::start()
{
    stopped = 0; // reset stop flag
#ifdef WIN32
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&startCount);
#else
    gettimeofday(&startCount, NULL);
#endif
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// stop the timer.
// endCount will be set at this point.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Timer::stop()
{
    stopped = 1; // set timer stopped flag

#ifdef WIN32
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&endCount);
#else
    gettimeofday(&endCount, NULL);
#endif
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// compute elapsed time in micro-second resolution.
// other getElapsedTime will call this first, then convert to correspond resolution.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
double Timer::getElapsedTimeInMicroSec()
{
#ifdef WIN32
    if(!stopped)
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&endCount);

    startTimeInMicroSec = startCount.QuadPart * (1000000.0 / frequency.QuadPart);
    endTimeInMicroSec = endCount.QuadPart * (1000000.0 / frequency.QuadPart);
#else
    if(!stopped)
        gettimeofday(&endCount, NULL);

    startTimeInMicroSec = (startCount.tv_sec * 1000000.0) + startCount.tv_usec;
    endTimeInMicroSec = (endCount.tv_sec * 1000000.0) + endCount.tv_usec;
#endif

    return endTimeInMicroSec - startTimeInMicroSec;
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// divide elapsedTimeInMicroSec by 1000
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
double Timer::getElapsedTimeInMilliSec()
{
    return this->getElapsedTimeInMicroSec() * 0.001;
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// divide elapsedTimeInMicroSec by 1000000
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
double Timer::getElapsedTimeInSec()
{
    return this->getElapsedTimeInMicroSec() * 0.000001;
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// same as getElapsedTimeInSec()
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
double Timer::getElapsedTime()
{
    return this->getElapsedTimeInSec();
}
```

Comment: I use a timer class downloaded from internet for measurement of time. I add the codes into my question.

Comment: Does the timer measure cpu time or wall clock time? The confusion of these two is by far the most common cause of why people think their parallelization does not work even if the program finishes faster.

Comment: In the downloaded timer codes it uses gettimeofday to measure the time. I think it is wall clock time. I have added the codes into my questions. Is it OK?

Answer (score 2):

A quick glance over your code shows a few areas where you can improve the performance. I'll leave the implementation up to you.

---

## OMP Parallel For

Firstly its **generally** *cheaper* to use

```c
#pragma omp parallel for
for (...) {
    ...
}
```

versus

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Not by much but there is a slight improvement. See [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74AfJ.png)], the graphic at the end.

---

## OMP SINGLE

The **key** benefit of using `#pragma omp parallel for` in this case is that it allows us to **remove** the `#pragma omp single` directive. When your program encounters a `#pragma omp single` directive **every thread waits** here until the others are finished processing their chunk of work. This *could* lead to a situation where several of your threads finish early and have to **wait** on another to finish until they can proceed.

Use of `#pragma omp single` and `#pragma omp barrier` is strongly discouraged in high performing parallelised code.

---

## Collapsing Loops (The Hard Way)

The next area you need to look at is collapsing your loops. The following

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int k = 0; k < o; ++k) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

will *generally* **parallelise** the **outer** loop `for (int k = ...)` but run the **inner** loops in **serial** on each thread. You can achieve parallelisation of the entire loop by unravelling them like

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int l = 0; l < o*m*n; ++l) {
    int i = l % n;
    int j = (l / n) % m;
    int k = ((l / n) / m) % o;
    ...
}
```

In most of your loops you can simply use `l` and the overloaded `[]` operator. Most Conjugate Gradient solvers will only need the `l` index and not the `i`, `j` and `k` indices as they operate on vectors. The only time when `i`, `j` and `k` are needed is when you are computing `A*x` (or `A'*x`). This change will increase the level of parallelisation in your code and should provide noticeable improvements.

### Collapsing Loops (The Easy Way)

It should be mentioned that OpenMP as of **Version 3.0** supports the `collapse(n)` clause which can be used to tell the compiler to automatically collapse the `for()` loops as I've described above. An example of this is

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(3)
for (int k = 0; k < o; ++k) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

which will cause the compiler to form a single `for()` loop and then parallelise it.

---

## Reduction Clause

Lastly, and probably the most costly element in your code is the `reduction()` clause. *Edit:* I incorrectly previously mentioned this could be removed after collapsing the loops in my haste to finish the answer.

[image: Overhead of OpenMP Instructions]

Source [[1](http://www.ichec.ie)]

Comment: I am skeptical. These changes have potential to speedup the call, but to make a non-performing one to performing? I am still betting for the measurement error.  BTW, I didn't get how you can get rid of the reduction of `s1` by collapsing the loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But the reduction for s1 and s2 is necessary, right?   Why can we remove it? I will try other suggestions firstly and report later.

Comment: @VladimirF, ZHAOPeng, Yes sorry I was wrong with regards the reduction in my haste to complete the answer. I've since edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know precisely why the OpenMP parallelisation doesn't make the code faster, but what's obvious is that you've got all you loops in the wrong order.
So, first thing first, start by swapping the `i` and `k` loops in your code and I'm sure you'll see a dramatic performance boost. Then you can have a look at OpenMP.

Comment: His `i` and `k` loops look fine to me, given he's using C and row-major ordering.

Comment: OK I hadn't realise that the `operator()` were actually accessing data in reverse order as the one given by the variable list. So indeed, the loops are fine but that's kind of confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My codes is rewritten using C++ based on old Fortran codes. So I try to keep them in original codes order for fast porting.